# Capture Uplink GSM packets using 820T2 and SDR

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, rtl-sdr

I am an extreme beginner with SDR. I am trying to use the [820T2 & SDR](https://www.petervis.com/Digital%20Terrestrial%20Receivers/dvb-t+fm+dab-820t2-and-sdr/dvb-t+fm+dab-820t2-and-sdr.html) device to capture uplink gsm packets sent by my phone to the nearest Base Station. I have an Rx Monitor App installed on my phone to see my Uplink and Downlink channel frequency (904MHz and 949MHz respectively). I am using [grgsm_livemon](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/gr-gsm/grgsm_livemon.1.en.html) on a Ubuntu VM installed on VMWare to scan for packets.
I am able to capture downlink data easily via gr_gsm. However, I see no signals on the frequency monitor of gr_gsm in the uplink frequency. I tried to move a few steps within the band to find any peaks, but unfortunately no result.

I also tried getting a call on my phone and then I see some instantaneous peaks throughout the whole Uplink spectrum for unknown reasons. (This is totally opposite of what I thought, I believed a GSM uses TDM and FDM for multiplexing multiple users. And a particular user would be assigned a static frequency and one or multiple time-slots for communication, and hence I should see instantaneous peaks at my uplink frequency only). Also, I am unable to capture any packets from these instantaneous peaks.

I would appreciate it if I get to know what am I missing to capture the uplink data or any tweaks to do it. In case you need any more information, Let me know. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
So I am sharing a couple of screenshots to have a better understanding of the problem.
a) Network Details normal. Here the Frequency hopping is off which is not seen in SS.
[image: UE Network Details normal]

b) grgsm output during Call. The peak is prominent but I couldn't take an SS as it's too fast.
[image: Frequency spectrtum during call]

c) Network details when I picked up the call
[image: UE during call]

d) grgsm DOWNLINK output

[image: downlink without call]

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: A) are you sure your phone is using only gsm900 and not switching to another band /mode? B) are you talking? The phone doesn't transmit much when you're silent, just 2-5 packets/second. Listen to the breakthrough with a cheap amplified loudspeaker to be sure.

Comment: yes, it is at GSM900 both with and without call as you can see in SS above. Also, the only thing that changes is that Frequency Hopping is turned ON.
Edit: Also I tried with a different operator, so you can see a change in Uplink and downlink frequency as 891 and 936 resp. B) Talking does gives some signals but no data is captured. And can elaborate the last line. I am sorry but what do you mean by breakthrough?